# How to make my text input dissapear after I press Add button?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Models/Transaction.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:MyApp()),

  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<Transaction> tx=[
   Transaction(id:'t1',title:'New Shoes',amount: 69.99)
  ];

  final titleController=TextEditingController();

  final amountController=TextEditingController();

  void AddnewTransaction(String title, double amount)
  {
    final newTx=Transaction(title:title,amount:amount);
    setState(() {
      tx.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar:AppBar(
      title:Text('Expense Planner')

    ),
    body:Column(
      crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start ,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:'title'),
        controller:titleController

        ),
        TextField(decoration:InputDecoration(labelText:'Amount'),
          controller:amountController
        ),

        FlatButton(
          child:Text('Add Transaction'),
          textColor:Colors.purple,
          onPressed: (){
              AddnewTransaction(titleController.text, double.parse(amountController.text));
          },
        ),
        Container(
            child:Column(children: tx.map((Tx)
            {


              return Card(

                child:Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,horizontal: 15),
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                        border:Border.all(color:Colors.purple,width:2),

                      ),
                        padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child:Text(Tx.amount.toString(),style:TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                          Text(Tx.title)
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )
              );
            }

            ).toList()


              ,)

        ),
      ],
    )

    );
}
}
```

So I want to make the text input that  I type is disappeared after I pressed add button,
here is my code, it is basically fetching the text input to the List. When I input the title and the text, it fetches the input, but the word "vincent" and "123" doesn't disappear, it stays on the screen. Can you tell me why it happens like that?

Answer (score 2):

update it in your updatenewTransaction setState()?

```
setState(() {
      tx.add(newTx);
      title.controller.text = "";
      amount.controller.text = "";
    });
```